# Laravel auto reduce the value while showing data

Tags: php, laravel

I am calling third party API to get few details and I am getting following output from that API

I am calling 3rd party API like

```php
$getDetails = Http::withHeaders([
    'Authorization' => "token",
])
    ->get('www.example.com');
```

Above is the API calling;

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "id": "dfdfdfdfdf",
        "primary": false,
        "hasCustomPin": true,
        "balance": {
            "balance": 0.2889486261378018117085275662248022854328155517578125,
            "gasBalance": 0.2889486261378018117085275662248022854328155517578125,
            "rawBalance": "288948626137801810",
            "rawGasBalance": "288948626137801810",
            "decimals": 18
        }
    }
}
```

Now but when I print this entire response then it shows

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "id": "dfdfdfdfdf",
        "primary": false,
        "hasCustomPin": true,
        "balance": {
            "balance": 0.2889486261378,
            "gasBalance": 0.2889486261378,
            "rawBalance": "288948626137801810",
            "rawGasBalance": "288948626137801810",
            "decimals": 18
        }
    }
}
```

[image: response]

Why laravel auto formatting number instead of showing the entire response as it is?

I do not find anything useful.